# Browse button for file upload 404 file directory not found

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

Hi I am currently trying to create an upload section for my website, i have looked at multiple websites and examples such as:

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

I have found out that there are multiple ways that these can go wrong for example mysql injection is each due to them using the `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`. So I have started to follow this link instead due to it being from php them selves, [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Ok to get to the point I have a problem with the code that I have at the moment I have a simple form that runs the PHP script to check the file upload and then upload if it is correct and come up invalid if it isn't this is partially working, the file uploads but if it is a large file I get a 404 file or directory not found error but if it is a smaller file size it works any ideas.

The HTML form is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000000" />
<!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
```

and the PHP file code is

```
    <?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = './';//
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

any ideas would be much appreciated or if anybody knows a better example to use.

Comment: You should check your php.ini file. not sure if you are running the code in WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP or any server?

Comment: The problem is that your php.ini file has probably set a lower file size than the file you are trying to upload.

Comment: @Bananam00n I am currently running this on a windows server 2008 R2 and where would the php.ini file be ?

Comment: Check this, it might help you out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: I'm actually out of options, except that it's maybe not the right php file...if you call `phpinfo();` you could see what the path is to your php.ini. if you see the phpinfo, try to fine `configuration file` or some kind. There should be a directory next to it.

Comment: here's a tutorial to call `phpinfo();` http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/

Comment: @Bananam00n I used the iis manager on the server and then it shows me the PHP.ini file for the version of PHP that I am currently using.it wouldn't be because of the version of PHP that i am using would it ? or it wouldn't be the file extension that I'm trying to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum file size may be limited in PHP. In `php.ini`, check the following properties:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

If it makes no change, you can also try checking memory limit or maximum process time.

Comment: This did not work what do you mean by checking memory limit and maximum process time ?

Comment: First, did you restart the PHP server after changing the `php.ini`? You must.

Comment: I have restarted the server and it still gives me the same error and I have also changed the memory_limit within the php.ini

Comment: That's strange. Tried `max_execution_time`? Are your setting high enough? Like `memory_limit = 100M upload_max_filesize = 100M  post_max_filesize = 100M`?

Comment: I have tried max_execution_time and I still get the same results and I have set each one to 100mb because the maximum file size I needed was between 10mb and 100mb

Comment: This is the best answer so far I still can't send the larger file sizes but i think it may be down to my PHP and not the server

Answer (score 0):

check your `upload_max_filesize - 2M` in your php.ini file

Comment: I have changed the upload_max_filesize and still no luck any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Windows Server, but I googled a bit and found this document:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_asp_net/3986574.htm

This says your php.ini file should be located under:

```
C:\Windows\System32\PHP\php.ini
```

if you found this file, find and edit the following lines:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

hope this helps! :-)

Comment: there is no folder called PHP in the system32 folder so i'm kinda stuck =/

Comment: and under your windows folder, is there a php.ini file?

Comment: I have found the php.ini file and I changed the maximum size to be as large as I needed it but it is still the same I still get the 404 file or directory not found

Comment: how high is your memory_limit in that php.ini file? change it to 128M if it's not on that

Comment: it is already at that size and i still get the error if I increase the limit size.