# where are the .htaccess file for windows server 2008 R2

Tags: php, .htaccess, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi I have got a problem with my upload button due to the file size being to big. But I am trying to find the .htaccess file to see if I can change the `max_upload_size`. I have changed this within the **php.ini** file, but just wanted to make sure that the .htaccess file isn't overiding the **php.ini** file.

The server that I am currently hosting it on is windows server 2008 R2 and the file directory is within the `c$\inetpub\wwwroot\Classroom.`

Comment: .htaccess is a Apache thing, there probably isn't one. You could pop in a file with `<?php phpinfo();` in it and check the value of max_upload_size there.

Comment: @hank that worked perfectly the only problem I have got now is to find out the problem with the upload button could you put this as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess-files are a Apache web server specific thing, it does not apply on IIS.

You can check the reported value of `max_upload_size` by creating a file with `<php phpinfo();` in it and check what the value is.

What message/error are you getting when trying to upload? Try to find relevant information in the IIS logs.

Comment: When I try to upload a larger file size such as 10mb to 100mb it comes up with a 404 directory or file not found but smaller file sizes they uploaded to the directory they should. So I opened up a question on here and tried the solutions from there  [My Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221327/browse-button-for-file-upload-404-file-directory-not-found)